# clear edite text because of wrong entry

Tags: java, android

```
public void onSearch() {

        EditText textEntered = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_userInput);

        String search_LocationText = textEntered.getText().toString();
        List<Address>addresslist=null;
        Geocoder geocoder =new Geocoder(this);


        try {

            addresslist=geocoder
                    .getFromLocationName(search_LocationText, 1);

        } catch (IOException e) {


            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Hi guys this is a part of my map app code in Android Studio, when I run the app it crashes if I enter a wrong entry like @@@ or a number. Can you please help that if the app won't crash if I enter a wrong entry? Thanks

Comment: What's the exception that's thrown? It seems like you're catching it already

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear on what the error actually is, but looking at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String,%20int)) I think it can be solved using using the following things:

- You also need to catch `IllegalArgumentException`
- You need to call `geocoder.isPresent()` before calling `geocoder.getFromLocationName()`

Documentation of `isPresent()`:

> Returns true if the Geocoder methods getFromLocation and
>   getFromLocationName are implemented. Lack of network connectivity may
>   still cause these methods to return null or empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

Apply filter(InputFilter) on EditText use a Regular expression of Alphabet

apply following property of edittext in xml

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```